# Class Path entry my.jar does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, jboss, module

So, I use Jboss 7.1.1 final and I deploy all my jars which are the resources of my.jar in a module created by me.

So, when I deploy the war file, only my.jar is there and the resource jars are in the module.

But, when I run the server these 70+ warnings appear: Class Path entry my.jar does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.

I know they are harmless but I need to remove this.

Any solutions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your war is working and you still got those warnings then probably in my.jar the manifest file is having jars which are not available as given.
Modify your manifest file to avoid getting those warnings

Comment: How can I edit the manifest file ? Do I need to unpack and repack the jar again ?

Comment: That depends on how you are building jar. If you are using ant then in jar task there is manifest tag using which you can specify Class-Path attribute